# Express Angular - Serve PDF

Tags: node.js, angular, http, express, pdf

I'm working on a MEAN stack app and i'm trying to display a pdf from the backend (Express) in the frontend (Angular). But everytime, the file gets corrupted during transmission. Does anyone have an idea ?
Here's my codes (simplified) :

**Backend :**

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as fs from "fs";

myController.getPdf(req:express.Request, res:express.Response):void {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', fs.statSync('myPdf.pdf').size);
    fs.createReadStream('myPdf.pdf).pipe(res);
}
```

**Frontend :**

```
import {Http,ResponseContentType} from "@angular/http";

constructor(@Inject(Http) private _http:Http) {}

this._http.get('ENDPOINT', {responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer})
    .map(response => {
        window.open(URL.createObjectURL(
            new Blob([response],{type:'application/pdf'})
))});
```

***Edit : middlewares :***

```
import * as compression from "compression";
import * as zlib from "zbil";
import * as express from "express";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
import * as session from "express-session";
import * as passport from "passport";
import * as morgan from "morgan";
import * as helmet from "helmet";

application: express.Application;
let _root = process.cwd();

application.use(compression({
    level: zlib.Z_BEST__COMPRESSION,
    threshold: "1kb"
}));
application.use(express.static(_root + "/node_modules/"));
application.use(express.static(_root + "/jspm_packages/"));
application.use(express.static(_root + "/client/dev/"));
application.use(bodyParser.json());
application.use(session({
    secret: 'abcd',
    saveUnitialized: true,
    resave: true,
}));
application.use(passport.initialize());
application.use(passport.session());
application.use(morgan("dev"));
application.use(helmet());
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it !

The use of fs.statSync('myFile.pdf').size as Content-Length worked well.

The problem was on the other end : the response had to be mapped on the blob() function :

```
this._http.get(ENDPOINT, {responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer})
    .map(response => {
        window.open(URL.createObjectURL(
            new Blob(response.blob(), {type:'application/pdf'}));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, Your "Content-Length" header is not valid. size methods of file system return string length in characters.

Some UTF-8 characters contain multiple bytes.

The better way would be to use Buffer.byteLength(string, [encoding]) from http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html. It's a class method so you do not have to create any Buffer instance.

Comment: Hmm... even with this change, the file is still unreadable in the output.
I've added the middlewares used, maybe one of them is messing with my transmission ?